# Php VS Java for Multiple file uploads simultaneously

Tags: java, php, file, upload

Requirements:

1) Only multiple Images, and small files will be uploaded.
2) Upload progress tracking.
3) No flash, no prebuilt library, trying to learn here.

Problems:

I tried PHP before, but the problem was APC allows only one file to be tracked at a time, so i cannot upload multiple files at the same time, like in rapidshare or mediafire which I am looking to implement. So i looked into Java, And it allows me to control file upload section completely down to the bit patterns and I know facebook uses that too so sounds like a good option.

So what do youll suggest me to do? Continue with PHP, some alternative or shift to JSP? If I should continue with PHP how?

Comment: This isn't a question of server-side language - both are equally capable in this case (of course, not if you constrain yourself to a library that isn't capable, but that's not a problem with the language).  Issues with multi-file upload are on the client side.

Comment: Why not flash? Penetration rate is ~99%. You don't need any visibile flash, just a hidden swf that you talk to with javascript/ExternalInterface. (That is how gmail handles multifile upload.)

Comment: I dont think its client side, I tried making multiple forms for multiples files and submitting them in an order, even that wont work properly, and as i said, APC allows only one file to be tracked at a time. What other option in PHP do I have that allows me to track file upload progress?

Comment: APC, like Alternative PHP Cache? What does this have to do with file uploads?

Comment: http://www.johnboy.com/blog/a-useful-php-file-upload-progress-meter

Answer (score 2):

What do you know better? What is the rest of your web site built in?

Those are better questions to answer than trying to figure out which language is better for this task. (They'll both work fine.)

Comment: Rest of my web site is built in PHP completely, but as I said APC only allows one file to be tracked at a time.